# JSP and JavaScript convert date

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a problem while trying to convert a specific type of date.

My goal is to get it into this format: `dd/MM/yyyy`

The current date format: `Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EEST 2013`

When I alerted using JavaScript, it responds that it is not a date. I used many solutions like to format it on JSP:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${theDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

Result error:

```
Attempt to convert String "Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EEST 2013" to type "java.util.Date", but there is no PropertyEditor for that type.
```

And even in Javascript:

```
var dateCreation = new Date(theDate);
```

The problem in JavaScript is that it says that `dateCreation` is not a date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your date string  `"Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EEST 2013"`

when i tried with your date string got `IllegelArgumentException`

change `"Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EEST 2013"`  to `"Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EST 2013"`  then working fine.

I'm unable to guess why you got that `EEST` (one E extra).

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date("Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EST 2013");
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

You are getting error in javascript because your passing the same string to JS i guess.

Comment: In jsp "Attempt to convert String "Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EEST 2013" to type "java.util.Date",

Comment: @neeldz am i misunderstood your question ??

Comment: i did try ur way and the strange think is the printed value :Thu Apr 04 08:00:00 EEST 2013 dont know where the 8 came from !!!

Comment: I bet ..definitely problem with the string you are getting from DB ..its scaring me..

Comment: Thx man it is really the problem i did replace using javascript EEST by EST cause all i need is the date and dont care about timing zone it works fine now.
even EEST its a time zone :EEST – Eastern European Summer Time

Comment: Happy to help.Please accept and upvote if you found helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

fmt:formatDate expects a java date object as value. In your case looks like theDate is not a date object but a String representation of date object. Please provide a date object and that should work.

Also in JavaScript what is the value of theDate param and where is it defined?

Comment: @bhushan..Please do not care about the downvote without valid reason. :) keep answering.

Comment: in my javascript the code is as below :
var dateVal = document.getElementById('theDate').value;
var dateCreationFiche = new Date(dateVal);

Comment: wich by the way it is from
<input  readonly="readonly" type="text"  style="width: 172px; " id="theDate" value="${theDate}"/>

Comment: As you can see the generated html value is not a date but ${theDate}. Are you sure you have pasted generated html and not the jsp code?

Answer (score 0):

The date object in JavaScript has the following constructors:

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds); // from epoch
var d = new Date(dateString); // "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Make sure you use one of them. Bear in mind that the month is 0-based for the last mentioned constructor.

Answer (score 0):

EST is GMT-05:00 while EEST is GMT+03:00. The difference occurs e.g. when parsing "Thu Apr 04 23:00:00 EEST 2013". Java (7) can parse EEST, but it can not format in EEST.

```
    String s = "Thu Apr 04 23:00:00 EEST 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d H:m:s z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date d = sdfParse.parse(s);
    SimpleTimeZone stz = new SimpleTimeZone(3 * 3600000 /* GMT+03:00 */, "EEST");
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(stz, Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTime(d);
    String ddmmyyyy = String.format("%02d/%02d/%4d", cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println(s+"\n"+ddmmyyyy);
```

In JavaScript:

```
function format2(s) {s="0"+s;return s.substr(s.length-2);}

function dateFormat(theDate) {
    //theDate = "Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 EEST 2013";
    var timestamp = Date.parse(theDate.replace(/EEST/, "GMT+0300"));
    var datePseudoGMT = new Date(timestamp+3 * 3600000);
    var dateCreation = format2(datePseudoGMT.getUTCDate())
                +"/"+format2(datePseudoGMT.getUTCMonth()+1)
                +"/"+format2(datePseudoGMT.getUTCFullYear());
    console.log(dateCreation);
    return dateCreation;
}
```